# Write a list of sets to CSV - Python

Tags: python, csv, set

EDIT: Looks like sets were used to build the dict, and the list was a list of those dicts.  @That1Guy provided the correct answer, mentioning that DictWriter solves the problem.

I have a list of sets that contains the following data:

```
{'dns-a': '93.184.216.34', 'domain-name': 'example.com', 'fuzzer': 'Original*'}
{'dns-a': '54.174.149.30', 'domain-name': 'examplea.com', 'fuzzer': 'Addition'}
{'domain-name': 'exampleb.com', 'fuzzer': 'Addition'}
{'dns-a': '104.130.124.96', 'domain-name': 'axample.com', 'fuzzer': 'Bitsquatting'}
{'domain-name': 'mxample.com', 'fuzzer': 'Bitsquatting'}
{'dns-a': '52.0.22.168', 'domain-name': 'exarnple.com', 'fuzzer': 'Homoglyph'}
{'dns-a': '64.57.183.2', 'domain-name': 'examp1e.com', 'fuzzer': 'Homoglyph'}
{'domain-name': 'exampl-e.com', 'fuzzer': 'Hyphenation'}
{'domain-name': 'exakmple.com', 'fuzzer': 'Insertion'}
```

How do I write this to a CSV where the first half of the set designates the column name and the second is the value?  For example, it should look like this if I open it in Excel:

```
dns-a          domain-name    fuzzer
93.184.216.34  example.com    Original
54.174.149.30  examplea.com   Addition
               exampleb.com   Addition
```

Comment: These are dictionaries, not sets, and they are inherently unordered, so you can't even rely on them appearing in order. Just pick an order of keys, iterate through each dictionary querying each key in the order you define with values separated by commas.

Comment: Not to be pedantic but that's 9 separate dictionaries - there are no lists or sets

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Comment: @That1Guy post this as answer

Comment: @jDo: You're correct that they're Dicts.  I definitely messed up there, but those 9 Dicts are indeed in a list.  Instead of printing the value of the list, I posted this instead so it was more readable.  I figured nobody wanted to see a giant comma separated list of those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), you have [dicts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict). That being the case, you should use the [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class in the `csv` module.

From the docs:

> Create an object which operates like a regular writer but maps dictionaries onto output rows.

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `writerows` instead of `writerow`. Your case:

```
import csv

data = [{'dns-a': '93.184.216.34', 'domain-name': 'example.com', 'fuzzer': 'Original*'},
        {'dns-a': '54.174.149.30', 'domain-name': 'examplea.com', 'fuzzer': 'Addition'},
        {'domain-name': 'exampleb.com', 'fuzzer': 'Addition'},
        {'dns-a': '104.130.124.96', 'domain-name': 'axample.com', 'fuzzer': 'Bitsquatting'},
        {'domain-name': 'mxample.com', 'fuzzer': 'Bitsquatting'},
        {'dns-a': '52.0.22.168', 'domain-name': 'exarnple.com', 'fuzzer': 'Homoglyph'},
        {'dns-a': '64.57.183.2', 'domain-name': 'examp1e.com', 'fuzzer': 'Homoglyph'},
        {'domain-name': 'exampl-e.com', 'fuzzer': 'Hyphenation'},
        {'domain-name': 'exakmple.com', 'fuzzer': 'Insertion'}]

with open('data.csv', 'w') as data_csv:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(data_csv, data[0].keys())
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data)
```